# Using Multiple GridViews

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm currently working on a website and one of the pages I have a requirement to display data in different GridView. That pages looks something like

```
<h2>First Header</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
<asp:GridView ID="FirstGrid" runat="server"/>
...
<h2>Second Header</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
<asp:GridView ID="SecondGrid" runat="server"/>
...
<h2>Third Header</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
<asp:GridView ID="ThirdGrid" runat="server"/>
...
```

In total I will have around 6-7 `Gridviews`. Each grid displays files from a different directory. Currently I have a function `BindGridView(string directoryName)` and I do the following for each grids `DataSource`

```
FirstGrid.DataSource = BindGridView("First Directory");
FirstGrid.DataBind();
SecondGrid.DataSource = BindGridView("Second Directory");
SecondGrid.DataBind();
...
```

My question is can I have one `Gridview` and change the `DataSource` or will I need all 6-7 and keep on working the way I am.

The image below is what I have so far.. Above the **File Name** is a main header for each grid

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are all these files supposed to be displayed at the same time or do they change based on another event?

Comment: @CamiloWard They are all displayed at the same time

Comment: Can't you have `combinedGrid.DataSource = BindGridView("First Directory", "2nd dir", "3rd dir");` and process all dirs in one method.

Comment: @artm That'll display everything after the first heading won't? Because the grids have different data after each heading

Comment: Ah you mean, grid1 has a heading 'folder 1", below that is "folder 1" files, grid2 has a heading `folder 2` and below that "folder 2" files?

Comment: @artm I've added a image on how I have it setup atm

Comment: You don't have folder names in the grid headers so if displaying all files together in one grid is ok then yeah you could bind all files in one grid. If folder name needs to be in the grid then add the folder name in that one method in the filename column.

Comment: you could do this with a nested listview

Comment: @naveen Can you provide example if possible please

Comment: http://www.codeandcloud.com/2008/07/nested-gridview.html my blog post. its ancient code. try using a nested listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example that use nested `ListView`.

Here I am using two classes `Directory` and `DirectoryFile`.

```
namespace WebFormsApp
{
    public class Directory
    {
        // the directory names like First Directory
        public string DirectoryName { get; set; }
        // the content that comes under header tag
        public string HeaderText { get; set; }
        // the content that comes under p tag
        public string InfoText { get; set; }
    }
    public class DirectoryFile
    {
        // file name
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        // download url
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The markup should like something like

```
<asp:ListView ID="DirectoryList" runat="server" 
    ItemType="WebFormsApp.Directory" 
    SelectMethod="GetDirectories"
    OnItemDataBound="DirectoryList_ItemDataBound">   
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h2><%# Item.HeaderText %></h2>
        <p><%# Item.InfoText %></p>
        <asp:ListView ID="FileList" runat="server" 
            DataMember='<%# Item.DirectoryName %>' 
            ItemType="WebFormsApp.DirectoryFile">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>File Name</th>
                            <th>Download</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Item.FileName %></td>
                    <td><%# Item.Url %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here the parent `ListView` has a `SelectMethod="GetDirectories"` that excepts `ItemType="WebFormsApp.Directory"`. The method will be

```
public List<Directory> GetDirectories()
{
    //assuming it will be a not populated from database. 
    // if so change your code accordingly
    var directories = new List<Directory>()
        {
            new Directory {DirectoryName="FirstDirectory", HeaderText="First Header", InfoText="Some Info"},
            new Directory {DirectoryName="SecondDirectory", HeaderText="Second Header", InfoText="Other Info"}
        };
    return directories;
}
```

Lastly hookup an `ItemDataBound` method ( it iterates through each item ) and find the child ListView. Please see that we have provided a `DataMember='<%# Item.DirectoryName %>'` so that we can access it at code-behind.

```
protected void DirectoryList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var listView = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("FileList");
        var directoryName = listView.DataMember;
        GetFiles(listView, directoryName);
    }
}
public void GetFiles(ListView listView, string directoryName)
{

    listView.DataSource = BindChildlistView(directoryName);
    listView.DataBind();
}
```

Hope the code is self-explanatory

Comment: Thanks for the demo, I tried your code and I get the following error `Could not load type 'WebFormsApp.Directory'.`

Comment: its the namespace of the class

Comment: Even if I don't use a namespace out I get `Could not load type 'Directory'`

Comment: this might help. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details

Comment: that example is not about nested listviews. Its about using ItemType. The code works on my sample

Comment: I totally appreciate that.. However I still get the exact same error even after using the exact code you've provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78405/discussion-between-naveen-and-izzy).

Comment: Thanks once again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Just use nested repeaters if that's the case. Unless you really need the GridView built-in features such as sorting, etc.